# RUST cargo run task with arguments in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust-cargo

Is there a way to specify arguments to a RUST cargo command running as VS CODE task?
Or should I be trying this as an NPM script? (of course, this is RUST, so I am using CARGO and npm, creating a package.json would be odd).

The Build task works fine:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cargo",
      "subcommand": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$rustc"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
},
```

But I have no idea where to put the arguments since I want it to be

```
$cargo run [filename]
```

```
{
  "type": "cargo",
  "subcommand": "run",
  "problemMatcher": [
    "$rustc"
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There absolutely is, the `args` option allows you to pass additional arguments to your tasks and you can use various `${template}` parameters to pass things like the currently opened file.

It's also worth calling out that the type of the command should probably be `shell`, with `cargo` being specified as the command itself.

For your use case, you may consider using the following (to execute `cargo run $currentFile`).

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "run",
            "type": "shell",
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$rustc"
            ],
            "command": "cargo",
            "args": [
                "run",
                "${file}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: While you are not wrong that this is the proper way to do it for a `shell` task, the `cargo`-type task is autogenerated by the Rust (rls) extension and there is no straightforward way to add arguments for tasks of that type